# Using polynomials as recursions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I made this observation in my discrete math course a while back.  I explored it further online, so not all the ideas contained are mine alone.  I still am confused about some things, though.  Consider the equation $x^2-x-1=0$ whose positive root is the golden ratio $\phi$.  Rewriting the equation we get $x^2=x+1$, and for nonzero $x$ we can divide to get $x=1+\frac1x$.  Now $x$ is defined recursively in terms of itself, so plugging it back into this defining equation we get $x=1+\frac1{1+\frac1x}$, and by continuing indefinitely we produce a continued fraction which converges exactly to $\phi$.  Returning to the quadratic, we see also that if $x^2=x+1$, then by taking the square root we have $x=\sqrt{x+1}$; since again $x$ is defined recursively in terms of itself we can plug it back into the equation to get $\sqrt{\sqrt{x+1}+1}$ and so on, to produce an infinitely iterated root that also converges to $\phi$.

What is this process/idea called where you find a recursion that 'solves itself'?  By that I mean that we had an expression for $x$ in terms of itself, which can be used iteratively to compute $x$.  How can one recognize that iterated roots or fractions can be rewritten as polynomials and vice versa?

Also, I find this argument of 'plugging $x$ into itself' to be very ad-hoc and non-rigorous.  Is there a more rigorous framework in which one could view this kind of thing?  And is there a way to tweak this idea so that a recursion for the negative root of the quadratic can be found?

Comment: I've converted your question to TeX; the math SE site includes support for TeX via MathJax.  If you're curious for more details on how this works, check the FAQ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are discovering [fixed point iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration), which can be a powerful technique.  You arrange your equation in the form $x=f(x)$, then start with some $x_0$ that you hope is close enough to the solution and iterate $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ to convergence.  If $f(x)$ is differentiable at the limit $L$ and $|f'(L)| \lt 1$ then it will converge in some neighborhood of $L$.  Intuitively, the distance from the limit is multiplied by something close to $f'(L)$ each step.  There are two parts of cleverness-you need to find a way of arranging your equation so $|f'(L)| \lt 1$ and you need to find a starting value that is close enough. If this process converges, you have $f(L)=L$.  Many times this expression lets us find the limit, which is the opposite direction from your approach.  For $x^2-x-1=0$ the quadratic formula gets us there, but suppose we wanted to solve $x^{10}+x-1=0$.  We could think that if $x$ is a little smaller than $1$, then $x^{10}$ will be a lot smaller than $1$, so the solution is close to $x=1$ but a little smaller.  So I will write the recursion as $x_{n+1}=\sqrt[10]{1-x_n}$ and start with $x_0=0.99$.  It converges quickly to $x\approx 0.835079069$. A spreadsheet makes this easy-copy down is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $N\geq2$ and define
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
T\colon&\left[1+\frac{1}{N},N\right]&\to&\left[1+\frac{1}{N},N\right] \\
&x &\mapsto &1+\frac{1}{x}
\end{array}$$
and note that
$$|T(x)-T(y)| = \left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{y}\right| = \left|\frac{y-x}{xy}\right|\leq\frac{|x-y|}{\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)^2}.$$
Thus, by the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) $T$ has a fixed-point, which is given by $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}T^n(x)$ for any $x\in\left[1+\frac{1}{N},N\right]$.

Next, define
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
T\colon &[1,\infty) &\to &[1,\infty) \\ 
&x&\mapsto&\sqrt{1+x}
\end{array}$$
and note that
$$\begin{array}{}
|T(x)-T(y)| &= |\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+y}| \\
&\leq |\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1+y}|\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}|\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+y}| \\
& = \frac{|x-y|}{2\sqrt{2}}.
\end{array}
$$
Thus, by the same argument, this $T$ has a fixed point given by $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} T^n(x)$ for any $x\in[1,\infty)$.